# Unexpected behavior from str_replace()

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have two arrays. One with color names and the other with the RGB values.

I am converting a color name to it's RGB value using `str_replace()` (then doing some other stuff with it).

All of the colours work as expected, except `Pale Yellow`.

```
$colour = "Pale Yellow";
$RGBint     = array('Red'      ,'Burgundy','Rust'     ,'Electric Orange','Pumpkin'    ,'Melon'     ,'Baby Pink'  ,'Candy Floss Pink','Electric Pink','Yellow'    ,'Pale Yellow','Golden'    ,'Lime'     ,'Kiwi'       ,'Mint'       ,'Dragonfly Green','Kelly Green','Fern'       ,'Forest Green','Olive'     ,'Teal'      ,'Baby Blue'  ,'Dragonfly Blue','Cornflower' ,'Medium Blue','Royal Blue','Electric Blue','Navy'    ,'Lavender'   ,'Lilac'     ,'Purple'  ,'Plum'      ,'Dark Brown','Chocolate Brown','Light Brown','Copper'   ,'Beige'      ,'Linen'      ,'Taupe'      ,'Shimmer'    ,'Silver'     ,'Medium Grey','Charcoal'   ,'Black', 'White'     , 'Off White' , 'Neon Light Orange','Neon Orange','Neon Light Pink','Neon Dark Pink','Neon Yellow','Neon Green');
$ColourName = array("200,16,46","166,9,61","150,56,33","255,106,19"     ,"255,141,109","255,181,73","245,222,218","245,155,187"     ,"239,74,129"   ,"253,218,36","250,224,83" ,"203,160,82","206,220,0","142,221,101","128,224,167","169,196,127"    ,"0,132,61"   ,"142,221,101","0,87,63"     ,"103,130,58","39,153,137","171,202,233","189,214,230"   ,"123,175,212","95,143,180" ,"0,51,160"  ,"0,125,186"    ,"20,27,77","149,149,210","144,99,205","51,0,114","140,71,153","99,81,61"  ,"105,63,35"      ,"134,109,75" ,"115,56,29","219,200,182","176,170,126","138,126,112","208,211,212","162,172,171","142,144,137","112,115,114","0,0,0","255,255,255","227,223,195","255,170,77"        ,"255,143,108","255,95,162"     ,"239,66,111"    ,"224,231,33" ,"255,233,0");
$RGBvalue = str_replace($RGBint, $ColourName, $colour);
die($RGBvalue);
```

Expected result:

```
250,224,83
```

Actual result:

```
Pale 250,224,83
```

I don't understand why it is picking up "Pale" in the result, this isn't the only two word color, and the others work fine.

I can't see anything obvious as to why this is happening, What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `str_replace()` finds `yellow` first (Because it's before `Pale Yellow` in the array) and after this it can't find `Pale` anymore. So use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) instead, like this:

```
$RGBvalue = strtr($colour, array_combine($RGBint, $ColourName));
```

Comment: Of course that makes sense now. I was expecting it to match the entire text. Many thanks,

Comment: @user2924019 You're welcome! And the difference now is `strtr()` starts with the biggest element to find a match, so it will find `Pale Yellow` before `Yellow`, because it is a longer word

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue change the order of Yellow / Pale Yellow in the $RGBint array.

Correct:

```
$RGBint     = array('Red'      ,'Burgundy','Rust'     ,'Electric Orange','Pumpkin'    ,'Melon'     ,'Baby Pink'  ,'Candy Floss Pink','Electric Pink', 'Pale Yellow','Yellow'    ,'Golden'    ,'Lime'     ,'Kiwi'       ,'Mint'       ,'Dragonfly Green','Kelly Green','Fern'       ,'Forest Green','Olive'     ,'Teal'      ,'Baby Blue'  ,'Dragonfly Blue','Cornflower' ,'Medium Blue','Royal Blue','Electric Blue','Navy'    ,'Lavender'   ,'Lilac'     ,'Purple'  ,'Plum'      ,'Dark Brown','Chocolate Brown','Light Brown','Copper'   ,'Beige'      ,'Linen'      ,'Taupe'      ,'Shimmer'    ,'Silver'     ,'Medium Grey','Charcoal'   ,'Black', 'White'     , 'Off White' , 'Neon Light Orange','Neon Orange','Neon Light Pink','Neon Dark Pink','Neon Yellow','Neon Green');
```

Comment: I think this is really inconvenient, since you would have to change the order   every time when an array element is bigger than the previous one and contains the element in itself. You would end up sorting the array by length and at this point you end up at: `strtr()`

Comment: I marked this up because it helped me to understand why this was happening. However later the arrays will be generated from the database, which will require more code to fix the order. strtr() is an easier fix.

Comment: Agreed.general rule of str_replace is that you start with the longest strings first - if you ever need to do something similar the str_replace way.